# Creating files with names based on entries in txt file

Tags: python, loops, file

```
i = 1
with open("randomStuff\\test\\brief.txt") as textFile:
    lines = [line.split('\n') for line in textFile]
for row in lines:
    for elem in row:
        with open(elem + ".txt", "w") as newLetter:
            newLetter.writelines(elem)
            i += 1
```

I have a txt file with names. I want to create files with those names like:
firstnameLastname.txt
The names appear in the files too.
At the moment it is working fine, but it creates on empty file called ".txt"
Can someone tell me why? If I'm right the problem should be in the loops.

Comment: `brief.txt` probably has a blank line in it somewhere.

Comment: Sounds like you have an empty line in the text file, probably at the end? Why not just check that `row` isn't empty before looping through it? Note, it is pretty standard to [leave an empty line at the end of a text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18789/301394).

Comment: brieft.txt has no empty lines

Comment: `for elem in row:` what is this for? Isn't `row` a string? Why do you need to loop over it without splitting first? Please provide a sample of your text file

Comment: And what is the value of `lines[-1]`?

Comment: I split it in line 3 with line.split(). And it works ;)

Comment: oh yes, why are you doing `line.split('\n')`? Surely you should be doing `strip()` instead? Have you looked at what is in `lines`? I suspect you are getting a blank line in every second element since all your lines probably end with `\n`... note that `"blabla\n".split("\n")` -> `['blabla', '']` notice the empty string in the last element

Comment: yes I get empty values but with your suggestion I also get every single char in one list and not in a 2d list

Comment: Please post sample data. Otherwise you won't get a clean answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an if statement to prevent creating files on empty lines

**Edit**

```
i = 1
with open("randomStuff\\test\\brief.txt") as textFile:
    lines = [line.split('\n') for line in textFile]
for row in lines:
    for elem in row:
        if elem == “”:
            continue
        with open(elem + ".txt", "w") as newLetter:
            newLetter.writelines(elem)
            i += 1
```

Continue will jump to the next loop cycle without execute the below code

Comment: Why not `if elem: with...` and then you don't need the `continue`.

Comment: thx for the help. I dont know why but I tried it first. Probably a tiny error :D

Comment: It’s the way I am. There are endless ways to solve a problem, use whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have so many loops:

```
from pathlib import Path

text_file_content = Path("randomStuff/test/brief.txt").read_text().split_lines()
for line in text_file_content:
    if line:  # in case you have a new line at the end of your file, which you probably should
        with open(f"{line}.txt", "w") as new_letter:
            new_letter.writelines(line)
```